# Already using height but vertical-align is still not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is how I structure the element

[image]

This is result so far

[image]

I have tried with both `<h3 style="vertical-align:middle;height:250px;">` and `<h3 style="vertical-align:middle;height:inherit;">` but nothing happens I tried to google but still don't understand which element should I style as `height:...px` and which element should I `height:inherit`

Please guide, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vertical-align` only works on inline elements (e.g. `<span>` or `<a>`). Since `<h3>` has a default display value of `block`, you'll have to set it to be displayed as inline, choose another tag or use another method of vertically aligning things (for example flexbox).